# Django Reverse URL Lookup Template Error

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm having a bit of trouble with reverse URL lookups in Django.

From the template:

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:save' post.slug %}" method="post">
```

From urls:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>\w+)/save/$', views.save, name='save'),
```

From views:

```
def save(request, slug):
    return HttpResponse("Not Saved.")
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'save' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post.slug` variable in your template is an empty string, but your url requires 1 or more characters (`\w+`). So Django builds `/post//save/`, but this url is invalid.

If you need to save a new post with no slug, use an optional subpattern in url:

```
r'^post/(?:(?P<slug>\w+)/)?save/'
```